# Node.js: how to listen to communication and respond on a single port

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, port

I'm currently building a remote debugging client for PHP in Node.js. [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php), a PHP library that allows for remote debugging, sends messages over port 9000 on localhost, so a remote debugging client can listen to messages and respond on the same host and port.

So, I've made a TCP server, which listens to port 9000, and after parsing the data, responds accordingly:

```
var net = require('net');
var transactionID = 1234;
var parseXMLString = require('xml2js').parseString;

/**
 * Create a server to respond to the debugger engine.
 *
 * @param  {Socket} connection
 */
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) { //'connection' listener
  console.log('socket connected to server');
  socket.on('end', function() {
    console.log('socket disconnected to server');
  });
  /**
   * When the debugger engine sends a message over port 9000,
   * send a response.
   *
   * @param  {Buffer} data
   */
  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    // Data comes through as a buffer, stringify it.
    var dataStringified = data.toString(),
      splitData = null,
      xmlStatement = null,
      dataLength = null;
    // Data comes through as a string separated by a null byte, so split it up.
    splitData = dataStringified.split('\u0000');
    dataLength = splitData[0];
    xmlStatement = splitData[1];
    parseXMLString( xmlStatement, function( err, result ) {
      if ( 'init' in result ) {
        var command = 'run -i 1234';
        socket.write( command );
      }
    });
  });
  // socket.pipe(socket);
});

/**
 * Listen to port 9000 to create connections from the debugger engine to the server.
 */
server.listen(9000, function() { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server listening on port 9000');
});
```

However, the socket/port is not written to.

I've seen `socket.pipe(socket)` used in other server examples. With that line in the code uncommented, the port does get written to, however, it makes a circular connection, and any messages sent from XDebug get sent back to itself.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more, who is talking to whom? Your Node script will listen on port 9000 and XDebug (from another server?) will connect to this port for debugging messages?

Comment: @TimothyHa Sure! I edited to mention XDebug speaks on 9000 on localhost, and my script speaks back to it via the same host and port.

Comment: Did you see server start listening? 'server listening on port 9000' - is that in console? And does netstat -an | grep 9000 show you that there is listener is up?  socket.write( command ) looks fine to me. I would also check if you are blocking outgoing data on port 9000 in some firewall.

Comment: Yep, I get `server listening on port 9000` when I start the app, and then `socket connected to server` when I initialize the debugger engine.

Comment: so probably you just never get into the condition   if ( 'init' in result ).  Can you add some console.log there?

Comment: It's not that the condition doesn't ring true - I can reach it. As I said in the original post, if I uncomment the `socket.pipe(socket)` line, the port gets written to.

Comment: Did you see the results of socket.pipe on the XDEBUG end?